# How to communicate an arduino code with ROS?

Tags: arduino, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
I want to commicate this arduino code with ROS. How can I do this ? Please help me ?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define MD22ADDRESS         0x58
#define SOFTREG             0x07 
#define MOTOR1              0x01 
#define ACCELLREG           0x03  
signed long int  pulse=0;
unsigned long last_time;
int ang=0;
int encoder_a=2;
int encoder_b=3;
float encoder_resolution=1024;
void setup()
{
Wire.begin();
delay(100);  
Serial.begin(115200); 
attachInterrupt(0,encoder_kesme_a,CHANGE); 
last_time=millis();
setMode();
}
void loop()
{
delay(10);
Wire.beginTransmission(MD22ADDRESS);  
Wire.write(MOTOR1);
Wire.write(220);
Wire.endTransmission();
if(millis()-last_time>1000)
{
ang=((pulse/encoder_resolution)*360.0); 
ang=int(ang)%360; 
Serial.println("Dc Motor Angle : " +String(ang));
last_time=millis(); 
 } 
}
void setMode(){
Wire.beginTransmission(MD22ADDRESS);
Wire.write(ACCELLREG);
Wire.write(0xFF);
Wire.endTransmission();
}
void encoder_kesme_a()
{
if (digitalRead(encoder_a) == HIGH) 
{ 
if (digitalRead(encoder_b) == HIGH) 
{
pulse++ ;  
 }
 else
 {
pulse = pulse - 1; 
}
}
else
 {
if (digitalRead(encoder_b) == HIGH) 
{ 
pulse = pulse - 1; 
 } 
else 
 {
pulse++;
}
 } 
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273055/how-to-communicate-an-arduino-code-with-ros?/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2017-10-15

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-10-15**:
Please add what you tried so far. Your post does not show any attempt of you to solve the task yourself. answers.ros is about helping, not doing it for you.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-10-15**:
I converted 2d laserscan to 3d pointcloud and ı want to use dc motor with encoder to angle data instead of dynamixel servo motor . So ı wrote an arduino code that  obtain an angle data. But I don't know how to communicate this code with the ROS. How to make the edits on this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can communicate arduino to ROS using [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino). I suggest you start with the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-10-15**:
Yes but there is a servo motor example in this tutorial, there is not a dc motor example

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-15**:
Yes, this is not a copy of the servo example, but the principle of subscribing to a topic and updating a hardware setting based on that data is fundamentally the same.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-10-20**:
I tried it but unfortunately couldn't do it . Please help me Mr. @ahendrix

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-20**:
As @NEngelhard said, we really need to know what you've tried and how it isn't working in order to help. We're not here to do the work for you.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-10-21**:
Normally, There is an example of the servomotor communicating with the ROS in the rosserial tutorials. But ı have dc motor with encoder. I want to communicate ROS with dc motor which is code above. I am asking how to make ROS communication with the above code. @ahendrix

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-21**:
Have you tried modifying the servo example by replacing the `servo.write();` function with a function that sets your motor speed?

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-10-21**:
That's what I want to do, but I can not. @ahendrix This code is getting angle data like the same servo.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-21**:
Saying that you cannot does not make it like you've tried. Please **edit your question** with the code that you're trying to use that includes your ROS subscriber and describe why it doesn't compile or why it doesn't work.